# Correlation between questionnaire to test validity

Tags: cross-validation, validity

I'm doing a validation of a questionnaire for my thesis and I should investigate the validity of my test with others one. To do so I've been asked to calculate the correlation between two scales and I'm a little confused on how to do it. I thought to use the Pearson correlation but I've always used it between two variables (e.g, anxiety and time spent studying) so I've no idea how to do it between my scales since one has 37 item and the other 6, plus one is a Likert scale and the other one is yes/no. Can somebody give me a hand to understand? Any advice would be appreciated! Also I'm conducting my analysis with R studio.

Thank you all!

Comment: This post is actually about validation rather than cross-validation. I recommend you read up on the former, including terms dealing with types of validity such as convergent, discriminant, predictive, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Do your scales allow to compute a final score? Typically, this could be to sum over the item scores, but have a look into the test manual for instructions on this. If this is possible, you can simply correlate the two final scores.